Illuminate\Contracts\Container\BindingResolutionException Target class [SiteController] does not exist
I am currently using v11, however, I also receive this same error.
Laravel Project\blog\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Container\Container.php :946
    }

    try {
        $reflector = new ReflectionClass($concrete);
    } catch (ReflectionException $e) {
        throw new BindingResolutionException("Target class [$concrete] does not exist.", 0, $e);
    }

    // If the type is not instantiable, the developer is attempting to resolve
    // an abstract type such as an Interface or Abstract Class and there is
    // no binding registered for the abstractions so we need to bail out.
    if (! $reflector->isInstantiable()) {
        return $this->notInstantiable($concrete);
    }

    $this->buildStack[] = $concrete;


Did you mean to include more code? Right now your code block starts with a closing bracket, which means you're missing some code somewhere, or you meant to exclude that first closing bracket.

The error is super clear, you are trying to instantiate SiteController, but you have something wrong wherever is happening, show us your route definition as I suspect the issue is there...
